# Поле select HTML + jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Необходимо выбрать нужный элемент в поле `<select>`.
Имеется переменная `var s = $("#Cat").html();`.
Точно известно, что она равна `"Кофейня"`.
Точно известно, что в поле `<select>` есть такой вариант.
Как выбрать нужный элемент в поле `<select>` используя переменную `s`?
Все что нашел в интернете не смог прикрутить...

Comment: `$("select").val(s);`

Comment: Нет! Не работает!...

Comment: Маленький гномик вылез из компьютера и сказал: "Не работает"? Работает!

Comment: Про гнома ты круто загнул! Но не работает..... 4 часа уже не работает блин ничего...

Comment: Смотрите пример кода в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var s = $("#inputText").val();
    $("#selectElement").val(s);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input:<input id="inputText" />
<br/>
Select:
<select id="selectElement">
  <option>-</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="btn">From Input To Select</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался! Ошибка была в другом! Очень благодарен!